# Tizen code to control the samung gear s3 watch buttons

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to write a tizen program which has to do the following

- When I do long press of any watch button then it has to call the specific emergency number

I do not find any sample code anywhere .. Did anyone already tried something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tizen native you can implement this by following the process below:

1. At first register a smartcallback to the button using the following line of code:

```html
evas_object_smart_callback_add(ad->button, "clicked", _btn_clicked, ad);
```

2. After that write the **_btn_clicked** callback as below:

```html
static void _btn_clicked(void *user_data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
   app_control_h app_control = NULL;
   app_control_create(&app_control);
   app_control_set_app_id(app_control, "com.samsung.call");
   app_control_add_extra_data(app_control, "number", THE_NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL);
   app_control_add_extra_data(app_control, "launch-type", "MO");
   if(app_control_send_launch_request(app_control, NULL, NULL) == APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE)
   {
     dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, "test", "error");
   }

   app_control_destroy(app_control);
  
}
```

**NOTE**: Don't forget to add the lines below in the manifest file:

```html
<privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/call</privilege>
<privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch</privilege>
```

I've shown the implementation for simple click event. You can implement the call action for a long press event in a similar way. For the implementation of long press event follow [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/code-snippet/native-code-snippet/long-click-implementation?langredirect=1).